# Solving a simple maximization game

Tags: java, algorithm, language-agnostic, maximize

I've got a very simple question about a game I created (this is not homework): what should the following method contain to maximize payoff:

```
private static boolean goForBiggerResource() {
    return ... // I must fill this
};
```

Once again I stress that this is not homework: I'm trying to understand what is at work here.

The "strategy" is trivial: there can only be two choices: true or false.

The "game" itself is very simple:

```
P1  R1        R2 P2


          R5


P3  R3        R4 P4
```

- there are four players (P1, P2, P3 and P4) and five resources (R1, R2, R3, R4 all worth 1 and R5, worth 2)
- each player has exactly two options: either go for a resource close to its starting location that gives 1 and that the player is sure to get (no other player can get to that resource first) *OR* the player can try to go for a resource that is worth 2... But other players may go for it too.
- if two or more players go for the bigger resource (the one worth 2), then they'll arrive at the bigger resource at the same time and only one player, at random, will get it and the other player(s) going for that resource will get 0 (they cannot go back to a resource worth 1).
- each player play the same strategy (the one defined in the method *goForBiggerResource*())
- players cannot "talk" to each other to agree on a strategy
- the game is run 1 million times

So basically I want to fill the method *goForBiggerResource()*, which returns either true or false, in a way to maximize the payoff.

Here's the code allowing to test the solution:

```
private static final int NB_PLAYERS = 4;
private static final int NB_ITERATIONS = 1000000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double totalProfit = 0.0d;
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_ITERATIONS; i++) {
        int nbGoingForExpensive = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < NB_PLAYERS; j++) {
            if ( goForBiggerResource() ) {
                nbGoingForExpensive++;
            } else {
                totalProfit++;
            }
        }
        totalProfit += nbGoingForExpensive > 0 ? 2 : 0;
    }
    double payoff = totalProfit / (NB_ITERATIONS * NB_PLAYERS);
    System.out.println( "Payoff per player: " + payoff );
}
```

For example if I suggest the following solution:

```
private static boolean goForBiggerResource() {
    return true;
};
```

Then all four players will go for the bigger resource.  Only one of them will get it, at random.  Over one million iteration the average payoff per player will be 2/4 which gives 0.5 and the program shall output:

*Payoff per player: 0.5*

My question is very simple: what should go into the method *goForBiggerResource()* (which returns either true or false) to maximize the average payoff and why?

Comment: Do the players remember what has occurred in the previous rounds of the simulation, or is each game started as if it was the first?

Comment: A fixed choice can't be optimal, try analysing a probabilistic strategy like picking the centre with for example 20% chance.

Comment: @brc: each game is started as if it was first : )

Comment: @Patrick: your comment looks like the answer that has been made.  How do you know that a fixed choice can't be optimal?  How comes for example the 20% chance?

Comment: You win 1 point by choosing the middle, but can lose 2 when too many pick the middle. So even just selecting the middle with a 0.01% chance is better than any of the 2 fixed choices, as conflicts are very unlikely with that ratio. There is some optimum ratio where the added chance of more points exactly compensates the added chance of conflicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since each player uses the same strategy described in your `goForBiggerResource` method, and you try to maximize the overall payoff, the best strategy would be three players sticking with the local resource and one player going for the big game. Unfortunately since they can not agree on a strategy, and I assume no player can not be distinguished as a Big Game Hunter, things get tricky.

We need to randomize whether a player goes for the big game or not. Suppose p is the probability that he goes for it. Then separating the cases according to how many Big Game Hunters there are, we can calculate the number of cases, probabilities, payoffs, and based on this, expected payoffs.

- 0 BGH: (4 choose 0) cases, (1-p)^4 prob, 4 payoff, expected 4(p^4-4p^3+6p^2-4p+1)
- 1 BGH: (4 choose 1) cases, (1-p)^3*p prob, 5 payoff, expected 20(-p^4+3p^3-3p^2+p)
- 2 BGH: (4 choose 2) cases, (1-p)^2*p^2 prob, 4 payoff, expected 24(p^4-2p^3+p^2)
- 3 BGH: (4 choose 3) cases, (1-p)*p^3 prob, 3 payoff, expected 12(-p^4+p^3)
- 4 BGH: (4 choose 4) cases, p^4 prob, 2 payoff, expected 2(p^4)

Then we need to maximize the sum of the expected payoffs. Which is -2p^4+8p^3-12p^2+4p+4 if I calculated correctly. Since the first term is -2 < 0, it is a concave function, and hopefully one of the roots to its derivative, -8p^3+24p^2-24p+4, will maximize the expected payoffs. Plugging it into an online polynomial solver, it returns three roots, two of them complex, the third being p ~ 0.2062994740159. The second derivate is -24p^2+48p-24 = 24(-p^2+2p-1) = -24(p-1)^2, which is < 0 for all p != 1, so we indeed found a maximum. The (overall) expected payoff is the polynomial evaluated at this maximum, around 4.3811015779523, which is a 1.095275394488075 payoff per player.

Thus the winning method is something like this

```
private static boolean goForBiggerResource ()
{
    return Math.random() < 0.2062994740159;
}
```

Of course if players can use different strategies and/or play against each other, it's an entirely different matter.

Edit: Also, you can cheat ;)

```
private static int cheat = 0;

private static boolean goForBiggerResource ()
{
    cheat = (cheat + 1) % 4;
    return cheat == 0;
}
```

Comment: lol, the point was not to make it cheatproof ; )   That said...  I made it on purpose that player had to use the same strategy (so no cheating) and based on the answer talking about the Nash equilibrium from what I understand that's kinda the entire point of reaching the Nash equilibrium: there **is** only one Nash equilibrium and both you and the other person found it.  The wikipedia explains that players will play optimally knowing that other players will play optimally too: so to reach the equilibrium player will end up using the strategy you guys both pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

I take it you tried the following:

```
private static boolean goForBiggerResource() {
    return false;
};
```

where none of the player try to go for the resource that is worth 2. They are hence guaranteed to each get a resource worth 1 every time hence:

*Payoff per player: 1.0*

I suppose also that if you ask this nice question is because you guess there's a better answer.

The trick is that you need what is called a "mixed strategy".

*EDIT*: ok here I come with a mixed-strategy...  I don't get how Patrick found the 20% that fast (when he commented, only minutes after you posted your question) but, yup, I found out basically that same value too:

```
private static final Random r = new Random( System.nanoTime() );

private static boolean goForBiggerResource() {
    return r.nextInt(100) < 21;
}
```

Which gives, for example:

*Payoff per player: 1.0951035*

Basically if I'm not mistaken you want to read the Wikipedia page on the "Nash equilibrium" and particularly this:

*"Nash Equilibrium is defined in terms of mixed strategies, where players choose a probability distribution over possible actions"*

Your question/simple example if I'm not mistaken also can be used to show why colluding players can do better average payoffs: if players could colude, they'd get 1.25 on average, which beats the 1.095 I got.

Also note that my answers contains approximation errors (I only check random numbers from 0 to 99) and depends a bit on the Random PRNG but you should get the idea.

Comment: I don't see there's any strategy that, in the limit, is guaranteed to be better than "return false" here.

Comment: See Frigo's answer to see how to compute precisely the probability needed so that the mixed-strategy is optimal given the problem's constraints

Answer (score 2):

if the players cannot cooperate and have no memory there is only one possible way to implement `goForBiggerResource`: choose a value randomly. Now the question is what is the best rate to use.

Now *simple* mathematics (not really programming related):

- assume the rate `x` represents the probability to stay with the small resource;
- therefore the chance for no player going for the big one is `x^4`;
- so the chance for at least one player going to the big one is `1-x^4`;
- total profit is `x + ( 1 - x^4 ) / 2`
- find the maximum of that formula for 0% <= `x` <= 100%

*the result is about 79.4% (for returning false)*

Comment: Haven't seen Frigo's answer when I was writing this - it is the same answer, just using `x = 1-p`

Comment: ah thanks a lot, it's basically the same as what the other user answered : )

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That only makes sense if they are allowed to use different strategies, not just a single one, in a competitive game.

Comment: @Frigo disagreed - I still think it would be interesting to maximize total profit using the same strategy but with memory... maybe to trivial.

Comment: They still need different memory (=different strategy) otherwise collusion will emerge from the shared memory, essentially violating the rules. It's a very fine line to tread.

Comment: @Frigo - different memory state is not different strategy. Like if a player got the bigger resource, he will go for the smaller the next turn.

Answer (score -1):

Mmm, I think your basic problem is that the game as described is trivial.  In all cases, the optimal strategy is to stick with the local resource, because the expected payoff for going for R5 is only 0.5 (1/4 * 2).  Raise the reward for R5 to 4, and it becomes even; there's no better strategy. *reward(R5)*>4 and it always pays to take R5.

Comment: I think you're not correct.  Both the other answer and "Patrick" commented that a fixed strategy, like you suggest, cannot be optimal.

Comment: It's not trivial. Everyone sticking with his local resource nets only a 4 payoff, three players sticking with the local and one going for the big resource nets 5 payoff.

Comment: But the players can't collaborate and all use the same strategy.  The "return false" strategy has an expected return of exactly 1 for all players, while -- as you computed at great length to get the same result I did -- the other strategy has an expected return of 0.5.

Claiming an expected return of 0.5 is more "optimal" than a return of 1 is a use of "optimal" with which I'm not familiar.